# envoy how to configure query_parameters not exist match?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

"sign" not exist match. how to configure?

```
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/log"
                  query_parameters:
                  - name: "sign"
                    present_match: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queryParams` of https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest and specify regex to not match your parameter